# Pull data from one table to another

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

> If 'Yayinlar' in table 'paylasan' columns 'Takip' in table 'edilen' column contains the values of the data to withdraw.

This is how I write a SQL query?
Query used Aspx.Net

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/DRDEqO.png]

example: According to the picture statements Osman's only be able to see the data inserted by the user test123

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: No, but I do not know how to use @un-lucky

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please specify your problem, and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: can you please attach screen shoot of the table??

Comment: @rafat  add photo and details

Comment: Not clear. Plz elaborate it more. Not a single column or table you mentioned above exist in your attached image.

Comment: @Tasawar I updated the table and column names. I added a example in subject.

Comment: what you wanna do is not clear.. can u please re-correct your english?

Comment: 'Takip' table 'edilen' column and 'yayinlar' table 'paylasan' column must be associated.
My purpose site users entering  just  should see the data of followed people. @rafat

Comment: i have added an answer.. Let me know it it worked for you. and give the correct sign also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this result -

```
select * from yayinlar left join takpin on yayinlar.paylasan = takip.edilen
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not get the results I wanted with the query you give. But the 'right join' I got the results I want when I use it.
Solution: "select * from Yayinlar right join Takip on Yayinlar.paylasan = Takip.edilen"